# What is the best way to do Automation?

Tags: salesforcedx, automation, python, selenium

I'm running into issues with Cypressio and Selenium, and I'm pretty new to automation testing within Salesforce. What is the best thing to do? How to do it? & what are the tools that you recommend to use?

Comment: What are you trying to automate, exactly? Component unit tests?

Comment: I'm trying to create new opportunities, create new leads, add, edit. delete records.

Comment: We use [Robot Framework on top of Selenium](https://cumulusci.readthedocs.io/en/latest/robot.html).

Comment: vendor solution Provar is interesting

Comment: @DavidReed could you teach me how you do it? I'm having some trouble getting into some of the fields inside of salesforce.